# SwiftUI Firebase Auth Error "Paths must not contain // in them"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my SwiftUI app I suddenly started getting this error once my user logs in (I use Firebase Phone Auth)". It happens right as soon as I do this:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("user").document(user.UID)
            .getDocument { document, err in
```

This is the error, the app crashes totally:
Invalid path (com.googleusercontent.apps.178114301509-gvnp7pp9tm6jq9s4rridgoae9glog8nj://firebaseauth/link?deep_link_id=https%3A%2F%2Fgigas-4f2dd.firebaseapp.com%2F__%2Fauth%2Fcallback%3FauthType%3DverifyApp%26recaptchaToken%3DTOKEN%26eventId%3Dmwkcoldfan). Paths must not contain // in them."

I tried reverting back my project with Github but I cannot find whatever happened that started all this. I don't even know what Path is the debugger talking about. I have seen people in other cases saying that maybe it is the id being empty so a / and another / collapse into a // making it causing such an error but it is not my case since I am sure the id is not empty.

Comment: What does user.UID log? 

There's a similar question that was answered that may be helpful: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61962393/how-to-solve-error-paths-must-not-contain-in-them-firestore-flutter-error

Comment: I will have to try again but when I tried it it was not empty.

Comment: can confirm that UID is not empty

Comment: What does user.UID log, even if not empty?